# An increasing parameter in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a parameter `p` and a dictionary `val_dict`:

```
p = 0

val_dict = {
    'p' : p/15
}
```

Is there a way for the dictionary to be automatically updated when I'm increasing `p`?

```
print(val_dict['p'])
p+=1
print(p)
print(val_dict['p'])

>>>0.0
1
0.0
```

**Update 1:**
Following the comments I made a function in the dictionary:

```
p = 0

def equation_calc(param):
    return (param/15)

val_dict = {
    'p' : equation_calc(p)
}
```

Though, it seems like it's still immutable:

```
print(val_dict['p'])
p+=1
print('p: ', p)
print(val_dict['p'])

>>>0.0
p:  1
0.0
```

Comment: Not unless `p` is a reference to a custom object, integers and floats are immutable.

Comment: you can create a function `add_to_p()` that can handle the update of `vat_dict`

Comment: `p` is a counter (among many others that I have) that will be updated several times. `val_dict` has some equations that need to be updated when the counters change.

Comment: Yea that makes sense. I think it's also what @Epsi95 was saying. Working on it!

Comment: @Reti43 please see my update. Not entirely sure if that's what you meant

Comment: Is there any reason why ``val_dict`` isn't a class instead, with an *attribute* ``p`` and a method/property for ``p/15``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi That's a good question actually. Initially I was thinking to use a dictionary because the plan was to continuously add keys and update values. But I guess I could create one class and have a class instance for each key instead. Though, I'm not sure how would I reference/call each instance specifically as their parameters change and update it. Do you think it will be more efficient/better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `'p' : equation_calc(p)` you store the result of the function to the key `'p'`. But this result is still an immutable object. What you want instead is to store the reference to the function itself, which you can then call later with your arguments.

```
val_dict = {
    'p' : equation_calc
}

for p in [0, 1]:
    print(val_dict['p'](p))
```

If you function is of the form `def function(args): return value`, and the value expression is short, you can also use a lambda expression, like this

```
val_dict = {
    'p' : lambda p: p / 15
}
```

Comment: Oh neat! I didn't know you can do that. Thanks a lot!